# Facebook JavaScript SDK help 1002

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am using the jQuery library for authenticating the user, using this script:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
    // Initialize the library with the API key
    FB.init({ apiKey: 'SECRET_KEY' });

    // Fetch the status on load
    FB.getLoginStatus(handleSessionResponse);

    dojo.connect(dojo.byId('login'), 'click', function() {
        FB.login(handleSessionResponse);
    });

    dojo.connect(dojo.byId('logout'), 'click', function() {
        FB.logout(handleSessionResponse);
    });

    dojo.connect(dojo.byId('disconnect'), 'click', function() {
        FB.api({ method: 'Auth.revokeAuthorization' }, function(response) {
            clearDisplay();
        });
    });
```

It is showing

> An error has occured please try again. followed by an OK button.

When I click that OK button it says:

> Sorry, something went wrong. 
>   We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.

Comment: Where is your handleSessionResponse callback method being defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation for the JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/):

You can see that your secret key is not needed, as the JavaScript is available for anyone to read. Facebook's authentication uses the domain of your request to verify that it is, in fact, your application.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
            channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // Additional initialization code here
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
FB.init({ apiKey: 'SECRET_KEY' });
```

Not secret key, just the application id.